# Trying to solve screen tearing issue broke vlc

Tags: video, vlc

Please forgive me for being a tech noob.

Discovered on vlc when playing a video with speedlines.

Problem persists on mpv media player and smplayer.

Attempted to look online for fixes.

Attempting to change output of VLC to X11 ended in failure. Problem still persists.

Changing window manager caused vlc to crash. Cannot play videos on vlc anymore.

Tried to change Look & Feel/MATE Tweak:

- changing to compiz: causes VLC to refuse to work. Upon trying to open a video it will automatically close. Also caused Ubuntu to have a problem. Fixes screen tearing for mpv media player & smplayer. Also causes every other program to “close” when attempting to change tabs. Meaning they cannot appear on compiz, even though they are still “active”.
- changing to Marco (Compton GPU compositor): also causes vlc to fail. Opening it is fine, but playing any video will cause it to close. Fixes screen tearing for mpv media player but not smplayer.
- changing to Marco (Software Compositor): ditto
  Sorry, Ubuntu 16.04 has experienced an internal error.
- changing to Marco (No Compositor): VLC fails. MPV media player: OK. Smplayer: screen tearing.

How do I fix screen tearing? 
How do I make vlc work again?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to post my specs.16.04.3 LTS

Comment: Used `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`. Actually fixed the broken vlc issue, but the screen tearing (for media players) still remains.